# Replacement for ContextMagic shell extension for Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, shell-extensions

For long years I have used the free shell extension [ContextMagic](http://www.contextmagic.com/menu-extension/) which provides in a cascaded menu commands like *copy path to clipboard*, open *Command prompt here*. The other commands (see screen-shot on the page linked) I only use very seldom.

Now I have moved to Windows 7 64bit and as Contextmagic is a 32bit shell extension it does not work in the most important applications like Windows Explorer.

I am looking now for a replacement that provides at least the two mentioned commands in a cascaded menu (I don't like overloading my main context menu it is already more than long enough).

Are there any free replacements available that are available for both 32bit and 64bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very good replacement called "[FileMenu Tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/)".
It is Freeware and works with 32bit and 64bit versions of Windows. Even more it contains a lot of functions, all configurable...